# VSCode : I want to change the text color(not background color, just the words color),whiich profile should I edit?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I have checked the Official Doc about theme settings, after trying too many times, I haven't made it. I want to change the text color(not background color, just the words color), which profile should I edit?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spended a few time and solved it. Edit your settings.json as below:

```js
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "list.focusForeground": "#00ff00",
},
```

Replace the color(hex) as what you want, the example code color `#00ff00` is green.

BTW, how I get this settings:

- Toggle developer tools(In vscode dropmenu of **help**)
- Try to find `div` where you want change, and get the color, for example (`#eeffff`)
- `command + shift + p`, and input `Generate Color ...` will show `Generate Color Theme From Current Settings`, select it would open a new file with full color configs.
- copy **all colors json code block** to settings file which match key of `workbench.colorCustomizations`
- search `#eeffff` and try to find relative key, if not sure, change color and try to see the color in your code.
- find out `list.focusForeground` is right. And keep this settings, remove other.

It might spend less or more time, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely! This is exactly what i need!